# Error al conectar android con SQl server

Tags: sql, android-studio

Me sale el siguiente error...

> java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference

Asumo que no llego a conectarme por que en el log llega hasta "Entro", ¿ademas por qué me dice null? Eso no lo entiendo.

```
public class Conectar
{

Connection ccnnection = null;
String cn = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.100.60.116;databaseName=CG_JUDICIAL;user=xxxx;password=xxxx";

public Connection conexion()
{

    try{

        Log.i("paso1","Entro");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ccnnection = DriverManager.getConnection(cn);
        Log.i("paso1","Conexion OK");


    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (SQLException e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return ccnnection;
}
```

Comment: Revisa el LogCat que error muestra, la conexión a la BD no se esta realizando. Tienes el .jar dentro de libs?

Comment: Si amigo, lo tengo te detallo el error del LogCat:

Comment: Gracias para obtener más información que ayude a la comunidad a ayudarte, @Misthios

Comment: at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6305)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24840)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

Comment: 2019-05-10 17:07:11.430 17979-17979/com.example.logindeusuario E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.logindeusuario, PID: 17979
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.logindeusuario.MetricActivity.consultar(MetricActivity.java:54)
        at com.example.logindeusuario.MetricActivity.onClick(MetricActivity.java:86)

Comment: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda, ahora se que no se conecta a la BD, será por el servidor que me bloquea?

Comment: Lo primero sería revisar si tienes acceso a esa IP y a la base de datos con ese password y nombre de usuario. Te puedes conectar con un cliente ?

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema es que no se realizó la conexión a la base de datos, suponiendo que los datos de conexión a la misma son correctos, puedo ver un detalle y es en esta linea

```
    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

debes instanciar el driver de esta forma:

```
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Revisa :
[JDBC en Android!](https://medium.com/@josealvarezvivar/jdbc-en-android-d0190c98689c)

Comment: si lo hice y tampoco resulta, sugieres que puede estar malo algún dato del servidor?, la empresa mi dio esos datos por tanto no deben estar malos. lo único que se ocurre es que el server me bloque, intentaré implementar un AsyncTask, la version del jtds tendrá algo que ver? estoy usando la 1.3.1

Comment: ya se cual es el problema, el servidor esta en el dominio de la compañía, por tanto para que se conecte tengo que usar la red de la empresa y no la wifi de mi cell. de todas maneras gracias Elenasys son un sol

Comment: Eso es importante, generalmente se usa un nombre de servidor y no la ip para evitar estos problemas.